# Scala type-widening/inference of foo[T](T,T): T

Tags: scala, types

Assume there are three functions:

```
def foo[T](a:T, b:T): T = a 
def test1 = foo(1, "2") 
def test2 = foo(List(), ListBuffer())
```

While test1 is of type Any, test2 does not compile. Why is that? Both List() and ListBuffer() are of type Any, so why is test2 is not of type Any as well? Also both of them are of type SeqFactory, so can Scala somehow infer that type of test2 is SeqFactory?

`foo(ListBuffer(), "")` and `foo(List(), "")` work as expected

Comment: The error makes me wonder if it is due to an implicit on `List()`.  Also it works if you do `def test2 = foo[AnyRef](...)`

Comment: Maybe it's because the type parameter of both arguments is `Nothing`? Have you tried using `List[Int]` and `ListBuffer[Int]`, for example?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug to me. Scala first infers `Seq[Nothing]{def seq: Seq[Nothing]{def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}; def companion: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq[Any]]}`, and then decides `ListBuffer[Nothing]` doesn't really fit that type.